# Can anyone pls explain this reduce code to me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reduce

I'm currently learning about the reduce method in JS, and while I have a basic understanding of it, more complex code completely throws me off. I can't seem to wrap my head around how the code is doing what it's doing. Mind you, it's not that the code is wrong, it's that I can't understand it. Here's an example:

```
const people = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 21 },
  { name: "Max", age: 20 },
  { name: "Jane", age: 20 },
];

function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const key = obj[property];
    const curGroup = acc[key] ?? [];

    return { ...acc, [key]: [...curGroup, obj] };
  }, {});
}

const groupedPeople = groupBy(people, "age");
console.log(groupedPeople);
// {
//   20: [
//     { name: 'Max', age: 20 },
//     { name: 'Jane', age: 20 }
//   ],
//   21: [{ name: 'Alice', age: 21 }]
// }
```

Now the reduce method as I understand it, takes an array, runs some provided function on all the elements of the array in a sequential manner, and adds the result of every iteration to the accumulator. Easy enough. But the code above seems to do something to the accumulator as well and I can't seem to understand it. What does

```
acc[key] ?? []
```

do?

Code like this make it seem like a breeze:

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
const initialValue = 0;
const sumWithInitial = array1.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue,
  initialValue
);

console.log(sumWithInitial);
// Expected output: 10
```

But then I see code like in the first block, I'm completely thrown off. Am I just too dumb or is there something I'm missing???

Can someone please take me through each iteration of the code above while explaining how it
does what it does on each turn? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `??` is the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) and `...` is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: The reduce method takes **any** initial value (or defaults). It's taking an empty object to start off with here and *(shallow)* merges the "accumulator" with `[key]: [...curGroup, obj]`. `acc[key] ?? []` says "use the object property at whatever `key` contains or if nothing's there use an empty array".

Comment: Here the keys are ages, the values are arrays of the people with that age. `acc[key] ?? []` says "if there's nobody w/ that age yet create an empty array so we have something to put the person into".

Comment: Tangential: when something isn't understood break it down by steps. All of this can be tested in the REPL/console, stepped through w/ a debugger, or logged to the console.

Comment: *"I'm currently learning about the reduce method in JS"* And that's a good thing, it's important that you have a good understanding of what it does. But unless you're doing [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) with predefined, reusable reducer functions, I recommend **not** using it in new code. (If you **are** doing FP with predefined reducers, go to town!) It's great for what it's for, but outside that realm, a simple loop is usually easier to understand and debug.

Comment: I'm sure a normal "for" loop is way more understandable and faster than that `reduce`, as on each loop it is creating a new object for the accumulator. And the same with the array, it's creating a new array every time a new element is added...

Answer (score 3):

That code is building an object in the accumulator, starting with `{}` (an empty object). Every property in the object will be a group of elements from the array: The property name is the key of the group, and the property value is an array of the elements in the group.

The code `const curGroup = acc[key] ?? [];` gets the current array for the group `acc[key]` or, if there isn't one, gets a new blank array. `??` is the "nullish coalescing operator." It evaluates to its first operand if that value isn't `null` or `undefined`, or its second operand if the first was `null` or `undefined`.

So far, we know that `obj[property]` determines the key for the object being visited, `curGroup` is the current array of values for that key (created as necessary).

Then `return { ...acc, [key]: [...curGroup, obj] };` uses spread notation to create a new accumulator object that has all of the properties of the current `acc` (`...acc`), and then adds or replaces the property with the name in `key` with a new array containing any previous values that the accumulator had for that key (`curGroup`) plus the object being visited (`obj`), since that object is in the group, since we got `key` from `obj[property]`.

Here's that again, related to the code via comments. I've split out the part creating a new array `[...curGroup, obj]` from the part creating a new accumulator object for clarity:

```
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
    return objectArray.reduce(
        (acc, obj) => {
            // Get the value for the grouping property from this object
            const key = obj[property];

            // Get the known values array for that group, if any, or
            // a blank array if there's no property with the name in
            // `key`.
            const curGroup = acc[key] ?? [];

            // Create a new array of known values, adding this object
            const newGroup = [...curGroup, obj];

            // Create and return a new object with the new array, either
            // adding a new group for `key` or replacing the one that
            // already exists
            return { ...acc, [key]: newGroup };
        },
        /* The starting point, a blank object: */ {}
    );
}
```

It's worth noting that this code is very much written with [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) in mind. It uses `reduce` instead of a loop (when not using `reduce`, FP usually uses recursion rather than loops) and creates new objects and arrays rather than modifying existing ones.

Outside of functional programming, that code would probably be written very differently, but `reduce` is designed for functional programming, and this is an example of that.

Just FWIW, here's a version not using FP or immutability (more on immutability below):

```
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
    // Create the object we'll return
    const result = {};
    // Loop through the objects in the array
    for (const obj of objectArray) {
        // Get the value for `property` from `obj` as our group key
        const key = obj[property];
        // Get our existing group array, if we have one
        let group = result[key];
        if (group) {
            // We had one, add this object to it
            group.push(obj);
        } else {
            // We didn't have one, create an array with this object
            // in it and store it on our result object
            result[key] = [obj];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

In a comment you said:

> I understand the spread operator but it's use in this manner with the `acc` and the `[key]` is something I'm still confused about.

Yeah, there are a lot of things packed into `return { ...acc, [key]: [...curGroup, obj] };`. :-) It has both kinds of spread syntax (`...` isn't an operator, though it's not particularly important) plus computed property name notation (`[key]: ____`). Let's separate it into two statements to make it easier to discuss:

```
const updatedGroup = [...curGroup, obj];
return { ...acc, [key]: updatedGroup };
```

TL;DR - It creates and returns a *new* accumulator object with the contents of the previous accumulator object plus a new or updated property for the current/updated group.

Here's how that breaks down:

- `[...curGroup, obj]` uses *iterable spread*. Iterable spread spreads out the contents of an iterable (such as an array) into an array literal or a function call's argument list. In this case, it's spread into an array literal: `[...curGroup, obj]` says "create a new array (`[]`) spreading out the contents of the `curGroup` iterable at the beginning of it (`...curGroup`) and adding a new element at the end (`, obj`).
- `{ ...acc, ____ }` uses *object property spread*. Object property spread spreads out the properties of an object into a new object literal. The expression `{ ...acc, _____ }` says "create a new object (`{}`) spreading out the properties of `acc` into it (`...acc`) and adding or updating a property afterward (the part I've left as just `_____` for now)
- `[key]: updatedGroup` (in the object literal) uses *computed property name syntax* to use the *value* of a variable as the property name in an object literal's property list. So instead of `{ example: value }`, which creates a property with the actual name `example`, computed property name syntax puts `[]` around a variable or other expression and uses the result as the property name. For instance, `const obj1 = { example: value };` and `const key = "example"; const obj2 = { [key]: value };` both create an object with a propety called `example` with the value from `value`. The `reduce` code is using `[key]: updatedGroup]` to add or update a property in the new accumulator whose name comes from `key` and whose value is the new group array.

Why create a new accumulator object (and new group arrays) rather than just updating the one that the code started with? Because the code is written such that it avoids modifying any object (array or accumulator) after creating it. Instead of modifying one, it always creates a new one. Why? It's "immutable programming," writing code that only ever creates new things rather than modifying existing things. There are good reasons for immutable programming in some contexts. It reduces the possibilities of a change in code in one place from having unexpected ramifications elsewhere in the codebase. Sometimes it's necessary, because the original object is immutable (such as one from Mongoose) or must be treated *as though* it were immutable (such as state objects in React or Vue). In **this particular code** it's pointless, it's just style. None of these objects is shared anywhere until the process is complete and none of them is actually immutable. The code could just as easily use `push` to add objects to the group arrays and use `acc[key] = updatedGroup;` to add/update groups to the accumulator object. But again, while it's pointless in *this* code, there are good uses for immutable programming. Functional programming usually adheres to immutability (as I understand it; I haven't studied FP deeply).

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to respond with such depth. Am not as foggy as I was before posting the question but I think I need to read further.  Actually the use of the spread operator the way it was in this example is one of the main things that threw me off. I understand the spread operator but it's use in  this manner with the acc and the [key] is something I'm still confused about. The accumulator is a single value if I understood correctly, so why use it with spread, and what exactly does the statement "...acc, [key]" mean?

Comment: @Tal - Yes, that `return` statement is very packed. :-) I've added to the answer to explain what's going on . Speaking from opinion for a moment: `reduce` is massively overused in JavaScript, I frankly wish it hadn't been added to the standard library, it's a niche utility and would have been better left to userland solutions. If you're not doing functional programming with predefined reusable reducer functions, don't reach for `reduce`. Just use a simple loop. (That's not just my view, you'll hear it from people like Brian Terlson and Jake Archibald as well.)

Comment: Appreciated so much for taking out the time to explain so exhaustively. The knot in my mind has been disentangled.  In case of further knots I will come for more guidance.

Answer (score 3):

You are touching on a big problem with reduce. While it is such a nice function, it often favors code that is hard to read, which is why I often end up using other constructs.

Your function groups a number of objects by a property:

```js
const data = [
  {category: 'catA', id: 1}, 
  {category: 'catA', id: 2},
  {category: 'catB', id: 3}
]
console.log(groupBy(data, 'category'))
```

will give you

```js
{
  catA: [{category: 'catA', id: 1}, {category: 'catA', id: 2}],
  catB: [{category: 'catB', id: 3}]
}
```

It does that by taking apart the `acc` object and rebuilding it with the new data in every step:

```js
  objectArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const key = obj[property];        // get the data value (i.e. 'catA')
    const curGroup = acc[key] ?? [];  // get collector from acc or new array 

    // rebuild acc by copying all values, but replace the property stored 
    // in key with an updated array
    return { ...acc, [key]: [...curGroup, obj] };
  }, {});
```

You might want to look at [spread operator (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [coalesce operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)

Here is a more readable version:

```js
  objectArray.reduce((groups, entry) => {
    const groupId = entry[property];
    if(!groups[groupId]){
      groups[groupId] = [];
    }
    groups[groupId].push(entry);
    return groups;
  }, {});
```

This is a good example where I would favor a good old `for`:

```js
function groupBy(data, keyProperty){
  const groups = {}
  for(const entry of data){
    const groupId = entry[keyProperty];
    if(!groups[groupId]){
      groups[groupId] = [];
    }
    groups[groupId].push(entry);
  }
  return groups;
}
```

Pretty much the same number of lines, same level of indentation, easier to read, even slightly faster (or [a whole lot](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/23082/4/reduce-with-spread-vs-forof-with-push), depending on data size, which impacts spread, but not push).

Comment: +1, `reduce` is lots of times overused. Simpler solutions are better. And I'm sure that this is even 10x times faster, as you are just creating one object, instead of one per loop.

Comment: @IvánPérez the only way to know that for sure is to benchmark it.  Keep in mind its the reference being created, not all the elements in it.  Put another way, its not like if there is an N element array, elements are added to a new array one at a time each loop.  Its heavily optimized and who knows maybe its just as fast or faster or uses less memory.

Comment: @terpinmd You can google that. `for` loops are [around three times faster](https://leanylabs.com/blog/js-forEach-map-reduce-vs-for-for_of/) than array functions like `reduce`. Push is [around 20% faster than spread](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/7699/0/array-concat-vs-spread-vs-push-spread-loop-apply), and spread is done twice in the reduce. Of course, if it gave better code, screw those few milliseconds (I don't think it does though). You are right of course, these things could change (but two spreads vs one push, function invocation vs builtin - I don't see it happening)

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, the difference between the two is ridiculous (apparently `for` is around 45 times faster): https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/23082/4/reduce-with-spread-vs-forof-with-push On the other hand, costs for spread probably grow linearly, while push is constant.

Comment: @MoritzRingler - Not a surprise, as you say array spread's cost grows as the array grows (in contrast, `push` is mostly constant time), and with a 10,000 element array, you're probably also exercising the memory management code a fair bit given all those object allocations (the accumulator objects and the arrays). JavaScript is great, but if you want to do functional programming (what `reduce` is for), it's not the best thing to reach for. :-) And conversely, if writing JavaScript, my view is don't reach for FP tools when non-FP tools do the job quite well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder People who do functional programming will staunchly disagree if you tell them that using list functionals is functional programming. Understanding the general structure of reduce does not mean that you can work with currying, pattern matching, lambdas, monads and whatnot. JS is a whole other beast, and if it gives you better code, you absolutely should use `map`, `reduce`, `includes`, `some`, `every`, `flat`, `flatMap` and so on, and they very often do that. `reduce` just happens to frequently give you worse code.

Comment: @MoritzRingler - What do you mean by "list functionals"? (I haven't studied FP, I've just been exposed to it a bit.) As I understood it, `reduce` was added because it was something the FP crowd (particularly one loud member of that crowd, no longer on TC39) wanted. :-) Perhaps I have that wrong. (I frankly wish the darned thing had never been added, it was a trivial thing to provide in userland instead in an appropriate context.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, calling them "functionals" is just a fancy way to say higher order function (apparently it is the mathematical term for a function that takes another function and applies it to a list). Doesn't really matter. As I said, I really like how clean and compact you can write certain things, like `const allGood = statuses.every(status => status.isGood())` or `const nonNulls = possiblyNulls.filter(Boolean)`, and I prefer the builtins to what lodash provided. But I think part of understanding them is understanding when not to use them (and "not at all" is a viable option)

Comment: I understand.  I am actually trying to understand the reduce method properly, and that's why I'm not going down the route of 'for loops'.  Actually the spread operator being used to create a new object with the ...acc, [key]; and ...current obj is what really threw me off. I understand the spread operator but when it's used that way with accumulator in the reduce method, that application confuses me. Thanks a lot for your time. I apologize in advance but it's likely I'll disturb you with further questions.